# why "main method"println is printing first

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, thread-sleep

I am trying to write a program to interrupt child thread.

But why `System.out.println("main method")` is getting printed first and then `t.run()` is executed?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class TryCatchReturn extends Thread
{

  public void run()
  {
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.println("i will get interrupted");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("catch interruputed");
        }
    }
  }

}



class Ideone
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    TryCatchReturn t=new TryCatchReturn();
    t.start();
    t.interrupt();
    System.out.println("main method");
  }
}
```

Comment: because when you call `start` then two concurrent threads co-exist, the *old plain one* that executes the main and the new one... It looks like the main thread is executing first its print.

Comment: The right answer probably is "Because". There's no guarantee on the order threads execute. If you add `Thread.sleep(1)` after `t.interrupt()`, you'll probably reverse the execution order (because of the system call in between).

Comment: is this only for interrupt?cause when I write same code using join() method of the thread, first child method is executed and then main thread

Comment: @Swati [`Thread.join()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) waits (= pauses the current thread) for the target thread to terminate. [`Thread.interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) just signals an interrupt with no wait.

Comment: `join` stops the actual thread and waits the other terminate so main can't print until the other is terminated. That is the intention of `join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the thread is not in the sleeping or waiting state, calling the
>   interrupt() method performs the normal behaviour and doesn't interrupt
>   the thread but sets the interrupt flag to true.

So as what Yunes mentioned, both the main thread and the new thread co-exist and run together.

Also have a look at [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/opr/test.jsp?filename=TestInterruptingThread3).

Answer (score 0):

You started the thread. Main method's next line of codes won't wait for your thread to complete.

Comment: @codespawner.means according to you first main thread will be executed and then child thread

Comment: No. It is asynchronous execution.  When you start another thread it runs asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, there is no guarantee on the sequence of threads execute as both the threads `main` and `t` run concurrently as you invoked `start()` method. `run()` method would have printed "main method" at the end as it runs on the same thread. Have run your program and I got the below output on debug.

[image: Threads output]

I too got your output on the first instance(without debug), which conveys the order is non-deterministic... :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: depends  upon underlying platform os?

Comment: nope, it doesn't depend on OS. If you wish to check which is printing first, add a timer to your log to print the current timestamp in micro seconds precision and check.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to multi-threading.

Here is what is happening:

1. First, you have one thread (the one in which the main method is executing).
2. You create a second thread (in the main method).
   -ma The main thread continues executing and calls the interrupt method.
   -mb The main thread continues executing and calls the System.out.println method.
   -2a The new thread begins executing and calls the System.out.println method.
   -2bi The new thread is interrupted and calls the System.out.println method.
   -2bii The new thread continues executing and exits the for loop.

The only guaranteed execution order is a follows:

step 1 happens first.
  step 2 happens second.
  all steps that start with "-" happen after step 2.
  step -mb happens after step -ma
  step -2a happens before steps -2bi and -2bii

You can't predict if step -2bi or step -2bii will happen.
This depends on the thread execution order.

If you change your loop from 5 to 5000000, then step -2bi is much more likely to happen than step -2bii

Answer (score 0):

When you run the program two threads will be created, one is the main thread where the main method runs and the other is 't' thread which is of type TryCatchReturn.

When you called the start() method inside the main() method, both the mainThread and t thread would have started and finished on their own pace. Sometimes mainThread might finish first and sometime t thread might finish its execution.

If you want t thread to finish first then you will have to tell main thread to wait for the execution of t thread. This is done using **join()** method.

you can also make main thread hold its execution for some time by calling **sleep()** method.